# How to customize ServletResponse in Apache Solr?

Tags: solr, servlet-filters, http-status-codes

**Current behavior:** 
No matter what the response is, as long as we can get valid reponse (for example, JSON) from Solr, the http status code is always 200.

**Expected behavior:** 
Within JSON response, we currently have other status codes such as 500(Internal Server Error) to be returned, and we need to change the response status code into 500 in http response header.

I know we can parse the response JSON, grab the status code and set it as http response code in a specific filter in filter chain, it may not be expensive, but obviously it takes time.

I am wondering if there is a way to overwrite the http status code when generating the JSON response in solr, so we don't need to do extra work in filter chain? I need it for both Solr 1.4 and Solr 4.0

Thanks for any help.